# android passing listview value to textview from another class?

Tags: android, listview, dialog

Im working with a dialog to pass its data to another dialog. Im trying to pass the specific content of the listview to the textView in my original dialog. How can it work?

here, it is incomplete i dont know what to code in the listener ... Thanks for the help

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_add_class_students);
        listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mySQLiteAdapter = new Database(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

        cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueSchoolAll();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Add1.this, InsertSubject.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        cursor.requery();
        String[] from = new String[]{Database.KEY_ID2, Database.KSCHOOL, Database.KSCHOOLCODE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rid, R.id.rt1, R.id.rt2};

        cursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_school, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_ID2));
                sdid.sdid(item_id);
                Intent intent=new Intent(Add1.this,DetailsSchool.class);
                startActivity(intent);  
                }

            });
        cursor.requery();
            listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected value as an extra for your intent in the item click listener

```
intent.putExtra("Title", itemValue);
```

In your second activity you can retrieve the value as follows:

```
String val = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title");
```

The section where you are creating the new Intent on listConent.clickListener

```
sdid.sdid(item_id);
                Intent intent=new Intent(Add1.this,DetailsSchool.class);
intent.putExtra("Title", itemValue);
                startActivity(intent);
```

The in the onCreate of your Add Activity you can check if the Extras are there and then extract the value.

That should work, but add a check before setting the textview.

```
if(val != null)
```

It is always advisable to cater for exception scenarios.
    String val = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title");

When you create your textView you can then set it's text using tv.setText(val). Make sure you check that getIntent().getExtras() is not empty and before setting the text to the texview check that val is not null.

Comment: thanks for the answer...  this is a bit noob :),.. but how do I exactly do that?

Comment: I set it like this:

String val1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title1");
         text1.setText(val1);

is this correct?

Comment: that really helps but why do my textView is still empty?

Comment: "listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {" in that code (the last part) I want to handle the things that you said but it didn't work, could you help me in solving this?

Comment: Please post your on click listener code and also the complete code where you are setting the textview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953786/cant-pass-listview-selected-item-to-textview there it is I posted it there ... Im really having a hard time doing that passing, btw thanks for responsing

Comment: I meant the updated code where you are setting the extras and retrieving them as well.

Comment: thats the updated code, i set the extras in the second dialog and the textview in the second dialog retrieves that but luckily it dont work