# can't pass listView selected item to textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I created two dialogs, the first one opens the second dialog that would access the listview and it did, the second dialog selects specific item in the listView and transfers that item to the textview in the first dialog... I messed up my logic, how can I do this?

here's the first dialog:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.add_students_dialog);

            imb1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im1);
            imb2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im2);
            imb3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.im3);

            text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text1);
            text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text2);
            text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text3);
            /* Get values from Intent */
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            String name  = intent.getStringExtra("Title1");
            text1.setText(name);


            ie1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
            ib=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_cancel);
            ib1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ok);

            ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent=new Intent(InsertStudent.this, StudentsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            ib1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String data1 = ie1.getText().toString();
                    String data2 = ie2.getText().toString();
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insertSchool(data1, data2);
                    updateList();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(InsertStudent.this, StudentsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            }); 
            imb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(InsertStudent.this, Add1.class);
                    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }); 
            imb2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(InsertStudent.this, Add2.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }); 
            imb3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(InsertStudent.this, Add3.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }); 
      }

     private void updateList(){
            cursor.requery();
     }
}
```

here's the second dialog:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.a_add_class_students);
            listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            mySQLiteAdapter = new Database(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

            cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueSchoolAll();

            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_ok);
            // Capture button clicks
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Add1.this, InsertSubject.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }); 
            cursor.requery();
            String[] from = new String[]{Database.KEY_ID2, Database.KSCHOOL, Database.KSCHOOLCODE};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rid, R.id.rt1, R.id.rt2};

            cursorAdapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_school, cursor, from, to);
            listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                    final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_ID2));
                    sdid.sdid(item_id);

                    Intent intent=new Intent(Add1.this,DetailsSchool.class);
                    startActivity(intent);  
                    }

                });
            cursor.requery();
                listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                    final int item_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KSCHOOLCODE));

                    Intent intent  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InsertStudent.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Title1", item_id);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
                cursor.requery();
     }
     private void updateList(){
            cursor.requery();
     }

}
```

Comment: Why can't you pass it? Is there some `Exception`? If so post Log or your output and excepted output.

Comment: it just happen that whenever I select the specific item on the listview the textview stays empty... i really dont have any idea, theres no error

Comment: Where is the dialog? I see new intents getting called :(

Comment: Ahh see it .. try String.valueOf(item_id) instead of item_id alone

Comment: the dialogs are ok and properly working, Im just getting a hard time in passing the listview's specific item through textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've called setOnItemClickListener twice for the same listview in your second dialog

Comment: I see,your " item_id" is an int,but your getting it as a string,try to use getIntent().getIntExtra

Comment: you can not set an int to a textview,do this
text1.setText(Integer.toString(name)),if thats not the problem,upload you log

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: the problem is parsing, i didnt parse it correctly, thanks to you I manage to fix it